# Invariant Violation: processUpdates(): Unable to find child 0 of element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting below error randomly while page load.

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: processUpdates(): Unable to
>   find child 0 of element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly
>   mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a 
>   when using tables, nesting tags like `<form>`, `<p>`, or `<a>`, or using
>   non-SVG elements in an `<svg>` parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of
>   the element with React ID `.0.1.3`.

[image]

I can see empty `p` there but not sure what to do with it or how to fix this. React doesn't throw this error each time.

Here is the code:

```
var React = require('react'),
    projectData = require('./../../projects.json'),
    projects = projectData.projects;

var Project = React.createClass({
    getCurrentProject: function() {
        for( var i =0; i < projects.length; i++) {
            if(projects[i].id == this.props.params.id) {
                return projects[i];
            }
        }
    },  

    getNextProjectId: function() {
        var currentPrj = this.getCurrentProject();
        var nextPrjId;

        if(currentPrj.id == 1) {
            nextPrjId = projects.length;    
            return nextPrjId;
        } else {
            nextPrjId = currentPrj.id - 1; 
            return nextPrjId;
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        var currentProject = this.getCurrentProject(),
            nextProject

        return(
            <div>
                <div className="jumbotron">
                    <div className="container">
                        <h1>{currentProject.title}</h1>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
                <div className="container">
                    <p className="text-center eeeBackground"> <img id="projectImg" src={currentProject.image} alt="Project Image" /></p>
                    <br />
                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: currentProject.HTMLdescription}} />      
                    <p>
                        {/* JSX if else condition*/ }
                        {(currentProject.link
                            ? <p id="website-link"><a target="_blank" href={currentProject.link}>
                                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right">Visit Website </span>
                              </a></p>
                            : <br />
                        )}
                    </p>
                    <p> 
                        <h3>Technology Stack</h3>
                        <div id="skills">
                            {currentProject.skills.map(function(key, i){
                                return <span key={i} className="label label-default"> {key} </span>
                            })}
                        </div>              
                    </p>
                    <p className="text-right">
                        <a href={'#/project/'+this.getNextProjectId()}>
                            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right">Next Project &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        ); 
    }
});

module.exports = Project;
```

**Update**
Nested `p` tags were causing issue. Replaced them with `div` and issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your empty `<p>` tags are generated as a result of trying to contain other `<p>` or `<div>`tags inside `<p>` tags. You should wrap them in divs instead

```
 <p>
        {/* JSX if else condition*/ }
        {(currentProject.link
            ? <p id="website-link"><a target="_blank" href={currentProject.link}>
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right">Visit Website </span>
          </a></p>
        : <br />
    )}
</p>
```

And here

```
<p> 
    <h3>Technology Stack</h3>
    <div id="skills">
        {currentProject.skills.map(function(key, i){
            return <span key={i} className="label label-default"> {key} </span>
        })}
    </div>              
</p>
```

I'm not certain this will solve all your problems but it should at least clean up the DOM to make it a bit easier to find your problem

Comment: This is likely the culprit; you can't nest `<p>` tags (and some other tags, listed in the error), so the browser automatically rewrites the DOM for you to "fix" it. Then, React can no longer find the DOM node it wants to modify, because they've all been moved around.

Comment: Thanks, replaced p tags with div and issue has been resolved!